# Tmeout in Linux in order to run a command for a certain time

Tags: linux, timeout

I am trying to run this command for 1 second:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables
epoch=$(date +%s)
u_id=100
id=1
timeout 5 echo $id",Danny_"$id","$id","$epoch","$u_id >> lfs.csv
```

It doesn't seem to run 5 seconds, so I tried to run it before execution of my script: 
`timeout 5 lfs_to.sh`. Which did not do the trick as well.

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com would be better place to ask such question.

Answer (score 0):

timeout command is limiting the command that you are running for the specific amount of time that you set.
in your case the command is finishing way before 5 seconds that you set.

```
[aa@vm007 ~]$ timeout 5 find / 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null <-- finished after 5 seconds
[aa@vm007 ~]$ time timeout 5 find / 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null <-- actual time that it takes to run with timeout command
```

and the output:

```
real    0m5.016s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.037s
```